# How to handle multiple hyperlinks in JTable cell?

Tags: java, hyperlink, jtable, cell

I have multiple hyperlinks in one cell of `JTable`.

If we click on specific link then hyperlink URL should be open in internet explorer.

Comment: So, what's the problem? It doesn't open?

Answer (score 1):

JTable supports html, it uses JLabel string parser/renderer, so you can insert e.g

`<html><a href="http://link1.com">link1</a><br><a href="http://link2.com">link2</a></html>` into one of its cells and it should work fine.

Comment: Hello, I want multiple links in one cell.